# Exact, Closed and Harmonic Currents on Compact Complex Manifolds and their Quotient Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-forms, geometric-measure-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold of complex dimension $m$.

It is well-known that, since every exact current is closed, we can define  $$D_{current}^p(M)=\frac{\{Closed p-currents\}}{\{Exact p-currents\}}$$

Since every closed current is harmonic ($\partial \overline{\partial} -$closed), I would like enquire whether it is possible to define the following quotients spaces $$H_{current}^p(M)=\frac{\{Harmonic p-currents\}}{\{Closed p-currents\}}$$

Comment: Can you recall why $d$-closed current is $\partial \bar\partial$-closed?

Comment: @ArcticChar First of all, $dT=\partial T+\overline{\partial} T$. We have $dT=0$ since $T$ is closed. Therefore, $\partial T+\overline{\partial} T=0$. Apply $\partial$ on $\partial T+\overline{\partial} T=0$ to get $\partial\partial T+\partial\overline{\partial} T=0$, since $\partial\partial T=0$, one finds $\partial\overline{\partial} T=0$.

Comment: The cohomology you defined here are very similar to the Aeppli cohomologies (see [here](http://eprints.adm.unipi.it/1612/5/10.1007_s00222-012-0406-3.pdf)), as least in the differential form notation.